# Laravel SQL Update Rows By WHERE IN Group By

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a little problem here.
Instead of running 10 queries inside for loop, I wan't to do it on one query.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
foreach($games as $game_id){
    DB::table('game_serials')
    ->whereNull('user_id')
    ->where('game_id', $game_id)
    ->update([
        'user_id' => 1
    ]);
}
```

So, I wan't to do it on one query instead of running this same for lets say 5000 users, which would be extremely slow to finish...

I have tried to do something like this:

```
DB::table('game_serials')
->whereNull('user_id')
->whereIn('game_id', $games)
->groupBy('game_id')
->limit(10)
->update([
    'user_id'    => 1
]);
```

$games array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
```

But it only updates 10 rows by first value from array.
How can I make it to update only one row per game_id in array?

Comment: can you show your array and a sample of your 10 rows ?

Comment: You question is very hard to understand. According to your first code, you want to set the user_id to 1 for every game id in the array. But your second code and request asks for updating just one row.

Comment: Hopefully explained a bit better. So, on second, it should update one row per game_id.

Comment: No, it is still not clear. Can you post a sql version of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: OK what he's trying to achieve is update the user id for one row of every row in the input array. Meaning he wants to assign one game serial to the particular user id from the list of games. This is best done with the loop you've used, but you need to limit the update to 1 result instead of updating all the serials with the user id like in your first code.

Comment: @plexcell Can you share your game_serials structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to achieve and took it upon myself to do this as a challenge. The below code is tested and does what you desire. It fetches the first free serial that isn't assigned to any user for each game in the list. The second query assigns the selected serials to the user.

```
$serials = DB::table('game_serials')
    ->selectRaw('min(id) as id')
    ->whereNull('user_id')
    ->whereIn('game_id', $games)
    ->groupBy('game_id')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('id');

$result =  DB::table('game_serials')
    ->whereIn('id', $serials)
    ->update(['user_id' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using loop. You can pass games array in condition. Please try the code given below-

```
DB::table('game_serials')
->whereNull('user_id')
->whereIn('game_id', $games)
->update([
   'user_id'    => 1
]);
```